# What Would The Result of Tangible Chaos Be On The Military?

Tags: science-fiction, social-norms

Backup Information:
This world is similar to ours, but it has a substance called Desonia that acts as a manifestation of chaos. Once damaged, Desonia integrates itself into whatever damaged it. If an organism comes into contact with Desonia, the Desonia will sense the chaos inherent in life and integrate itself into said organism. Such an organism is called a Dissonant, and the infection is called Dissonance Syndrome.

Dissonants exhibit supernatural abilities ranging from being able to tunnel through rock or heal allies to elemancy (manipulating and/or generating elements, like fire or darkness). If you're confused, they're similar to X-Men in that their held abilities are unnatural and could be just about any power you can think of, but the more powerful the ability, the rarer it is.

However, Dissonants have *chaos* inside them. This makes them more likely to gain genetic defects, such as cancer, and that possibility grows every time an individual overexerts their power or is exposed to Desonia. To offset this, it is possible for a Dissonant's inner Desonia to be 'harmonized,' or integrated fully with their natural energies, turning them into a Resonant. Resonants have enhanced healing factors and abilities, so they're quite valuable, but as of yet, no one has yet determined how to reliably create Resonants. It *is* established that someone with a 'special something,' part of which is a strong sense of self, can somehow become a Resonant through....willpower? Science is at a loss.

When integrated into an *organism,* Desonia grants superpowers. When integrated into an *object,* however, it simply enhances that given object's function. For example, a Desonia-infused gun would absorb ambient energy and turn it into ammo. While it is possible to infuse one object (see the gun example above, or think of a computer) made out of multiple parts with Desonia, something as complex as a plane or car cannot integrate Desonia by damaging it. Its components would have to be Desonia-infused for it to be enhanced.

My question is, in a world exactly like ours but with the above changes, how would the military utilize Desonia? The military in this case has to both defend their home country and deter threats.

Comment: I hope this is more focused-I'm new here and this is my second question, so I'm doing my best.

Comment: It would be better to edit the previous question with the content you have posted here, since this is just one of the 3 questions you had there.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that.

Comment: As asked, this question is too broad. "the military" even for a small country is a very large, very complex organization and the issues can range from the acquisition of pencils for one base to strategic decisions for a specific battle to everything under the sun. In other words, this is very, very broad and there's no way for you to judge a best answer. Do you have a specific question about the military? The more specific your question, the less likely it will be closed.

Comment: Most soldiers will become civilians again after a couple years -- does somebody yank out their superpowers? Or are neighborhoods routinely devastated by flare-ups among middle-aged accountants and salesmen during football matches? Are care homes routinely slaughtered by superpowered elderly residents with dementia?

Comment: Oh, and what happens if a baby gets infused? Super-powered baby pulps their family (and the entire block) in a fit of pique over a diaper change?

Comment: That's a very good question. It's likely that the military would avoid Desonia altogether except for use in enhancing technology (see below). Now, if you could find a useful military application for Desonia, that'd be great. Bonus points if you figure out how to create Resonants!

Comment: Above I put "similar to ours." Also, even with Desonia enhancements, a baby would be unlikely to pulp even one person, let alone a block. The greater the power (or by extension, trait), the rarer it is. It would take all kinds of mutation, not to mention supernatural power, to have the destructive power you're imagining.

Comment: Is the infusing of an object *predictable*? If I infuse the bolts of 100 rifles with 3g of DS, will I get the same result 100 times? Or is the result chaotic?

Comment: Actually, yes. The Desonia is integrating into an object, essentially becoming one with the object. The problem with lifeforms is that there are too many variables. There are about 120,000 mistakes made when recombing DNA during cell division, which is a very large margin for error, and therefore a very large possibility of harmful mutation....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117039/discussion-between-alendyias-and-user535733).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The country with the most Desonia wins all wars.

Now all those effects of DS you listed there were making someone superpowered, but this one pronoun kind of gives an insight here:

> Integrates itself into *whatever* damaged it

This implies not only can we make super heros from it, we can make super powered military units.

1. Start mining raw Desonia ore.
2. Transport it undamaged using existing logistics networks.
3. Give some to the airforce:

   1. Roll plane out of aircraft factory.
   2. Place some Desonia on ground in front of it.
   3. Plane runs over it.
   4. Now your planes have super powers. They can fly really fast. They have infinite ammo. They can fly really high. They can go invisible. Etc.
4. Give some to the navy.

   1. As a ship rolls down the launch way into the harbour, it crushes some Desonia.
   2. Now your ship has super powers.
   3. They can go invisible. They can go really fast. They can spawn a tsunami. Etc.
5. Give some to the army.

   1. Men walk up to it on their last day of basic training and smash some.
   2. Now the men are superpowered.
   3. You now have a super powered army.
6. Cyber command could create superman hackers.
7. Space force could create super powered rocket ships.

This stuff seems overpowered if anything.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but damaging Desonia causes it to integrate into an object. In other words, mining it would infuse the equipment used and nothing else.....

Comment: The mining equipment would only  mine around the Desonia

Comment: So is destonia edible or is it like nom nom this quartz is yummy?

Comment: Edible? This is chaos we're talking about here, eating it is not exactly the best idea! Look above and you'll see that eating Desonia can have the same effect as ingesting a carcinogen!