# Possibility of Spirit Remnant-absorbing Character Creating Organism

Tags: magic

I'm sure you're confused, so here's the context:

The character, Ember, is infused with Desonia (a solid manifestation of chaos). As a result, she has the holds the following abilities and effects:

1. Fiery Fury-Ember can create and manipulate flames at the cost of energy, specifically the same energy that sustains her body.
2. Light the Torch-Either imbues Ember's attacks, even her weapon attacks, with fire for the duration or doubles the power of her pyromancy (along with the energy cost). Costs a reasonable amount of energy for the duration.
3. Ascendant Flame-Somehow, Ember's durability, health, stamina, speed, agility-what a video game would term stats-increase a certain amount upon defeating an enemy or being promoted in the organization she belongs to, Resonance.
4. Pass the Torch-Ember transfers a fourth of her power to an ally, rendering them fireproof and granting them pyromancy and any stat boosts she currently holds from Ascendant Flame.

The trouble is, Desonia is actually pieces of solidified life force from a god-like chaos dragon. Later, Ember came across a shard of unusual crystal and touched it, unaware that this crystal contained some life force from a powerful (but NOT godlike) Dark Fire dragon. Don't worry about the feasibility of this occurring, here's the real problem: if you combine life force from two members of the same species, it creates an organism, and after absorbing the crystal's energies, Ember had to be brought into a special pod so she could be 'evolved' (ie. have her genes recombined) so she could survive the power surge and use her newly transformed abilies. After she came out, she was Resonant, which means she integrated the Desonia inside her perfectly with her natural energies (essentially absorbing that piece of chaos dragon essence).

My question is two-part and goes like this:

1. What would the results be?
2. If an organism would be created through the fusion (your choice whether Ember absorbed just the *power* of the chaos dragon or the *life force* of the chaos dragon as well), what would it be like?

**Please note:**

1. Any time essence from two creatures of the same type (in this case, dragon) combines (along with enough material to provide an 'embryo'), an organism of that species type (or a hybrid of their species) is created. The question is, does Ember absorb the Desonia (chaos dragon essence), therefore turning it into 'human' life force before this organism can be created? Or if she does absorb it before that happens, does it still count as draconic essence since it's essentially the same but with a little 'extra'-the 'extra' being human essence-added in?
2. As you can see above, Ember is a Resonant (superhuman) with the power of pyromancy. Her body is enhanced and she has a quickened healing factor. Think of a high-level RPG fighter, but with unusually quick regeneration (enough to grow an arm back in about half a minute).
   Her vitality (what DnD calls Constitution) is incredibly high, making her ability much more useful. After 'evolving' into a Resonant, Ember gains draconic features: scales, fangs, horns, claws, tail, and so on.
3. A chaos dragon has the ability to disrupt reality or order in a desired way. For examples:
   a. Making a machine break or malfunction
   b. Warping or altering material (or even molecular structures)
   c. Altering reality in the area (think of certain RPGS where wizards gain the ability to transform the surrounding area at high levels, an example of which would be negating gravity).
4. A dark fire dragon is simply a dragon that holds the powers of fire and darkness. So, their abilities include:
   a. Pyromancy-generating and manipulating flames
   b. Umbramancy-Creating and/or manipulating shadows or darkness
   c. Dark Magic Casting-Destructive magic, HP-stealing magic, Curses, I think you get the idea.....

Comment: What are the objective criteria for assessing answers?  Without some idea of how answers will be judged, this risks being closed as purely opinion-based.  A separate issue is that the question gives no information regarding what a Dark Fire dragon is, except the wording of part 2 of the question indicates that it is a "chaos dragon", which also is not defined.

Comment: You are asking about things in your world without explaining the full context for them.
Since magic follows its own rules set by the creator, you here. 
We simply have no frame of reference to answer or engage in your question in anyway without you giving us the full details.
This is not a place for general ideas. Like I can provide opinions on how I'd tackle that problem but that would make it opinion based.
I think you need to explain the problem while providing the clear and relevant laws so we can try to solve it.
Waiting for some clarification before VTCing though

Comment: Sorry, KerrAvon. In part 2, I was referring to the Desonia, as whether Ember absorbs it before it can combine to form an organism or how she absorbs it (just the power, or the life force it contains as well) has huge bearing on the answer. Seallussus, I added more context, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, garnering up more background information from [your other question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/191451/what-would-the-result-of-tangible-chaos-be-on-the-military), it seems from the statement:

> When integrated into an *organism*, Desonia grants superpowers.

that Ember should only receive the powers that come from integrating Desonia (Resonance), and not face changes / have her life force altered / be at the mercy of chaos.

However, this raises the question of "what happens to the combined life forces of the Chaos Dragon and Dark-Fire Dragon between when Ember touches the Dark-Fire Dragon crystal and when she's evolved in the pod?" Your question already has a perfectly valid answer for this. Namely, that *Ember develops draconic features*.

If a resonant is a human who gets to retain his / her humanity after integrating the chaos that is Desonia, then we can explain Ember's claws, tail, etc. as a byproduct of the reaction that began between the life forces of the two dragons, which was integrated into Ember's own life force during the evolution process. This means that when Ember turned resonant, she didn't do so as a full "human", but as something else; a mix of her own humanity and the draconic life that began to form between the life forces of the two dragons, leading to her half human, half dragon form.

Comment: That's a really good answer! Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: However, my problem is that it's perfectly viable that the life force inside the Desonia is drawn to its nearest equivalent, the life force from the Dark Fire Dragon's crystal and therefore combines to create an organism, leaving Ember with draconic features from the combined power of both dragons and new life inside her from the fusion of life force.

Comment: @Alendyias Thank you kindly!
At the end of the day, it comes down to the preference of you, the author as it's effectively a "how do the rules of my world work" question, rather than "how do the rules of my world dictate this scenario would happen".
So far, there are seemingly few restrictions, so Ember could indeed fall dragon-pregnant or have a draconic tumour begin growing in her, or have her own life force combine with the dragon embryo or whatever else you'd like. :)

Comment: That is the crux of the problem here: there are all these possibilities and I'm trying to find  the most likely one.

Comment: Well, no one can really speak to the "likelihood" of any one given possibility. At the end of the day, it's completely arbitrary and up to you, the author. All that's important is that none of the above suggested choices _violate_ the rules / precedent of your world. That being said, if the answer was helpful, feel free to vote. :)

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help!  I'll analyze the given possibilities and make my decision.

Answer (score 1):

They can of course be whatever you want them to be.  But thinking of the storyline potential:

1:  Ember's fighting abilities are established as you have laid out; ok.

2:  The human character of Ember can always be established more because that is why people keep reading.

3:  New life has formed inside Ember.

4. **Ember has a baby.**

This is going to be a funky baby, yes indeed.  It has 2 dragon daddies and Ember is not your typical mom.  But it will be a little fusser as babies are.  We will learn about Ember as she raises her magic dragon baby.

I think magic dragon baby would get born in the third book in the series.  Dragon baby will be 10 years old by the 5th and final book and a fine little wingman.

Comment: After giving your question due consideration, yes, it's perfectly likely that Ember has a baby. However, that baby won't just be a dragon, because the Desonia that went into its creation was irrevocably altered by Ember's essence. The end result would be therefore quite like a Dragonborn in DnD. I especially appreciate your idea of how the baby can fit into the plot and become a 'fine little wingman.'